# SimpleDateFormate not working with colon ":" on time format

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to capture screenshot for those failed test cases with the method name along with date and timestamps. below pic of code is working when I use anything other than colon ie. simpleDateFormat("MMM d yyyy hh:mm:ss"). 
Meaning Below code is working just fine.

```
public void getScreenshots(String imgName) throws IOException{
        File image = enter code here((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        System.out.println(image);
        String screenShotLocation =(".\\src\\main\\java\\com\\phpTravels\\screenshots\\");
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yyyy hh.mm.ss");
        Date localDate = new Date();
        String finalImage = (screenShotLocation+ dateFormat.format(localDate)+"_" +imgName +".png");
        System.out.println(finalImage);
        FileUtils.copyFile(image, new File(finalImage));
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. It works when using colon...

Comment: maybe show us what **isn't** working

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Date conversion will work as expected, try to execute only the below code:

```
DateFormat formate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(formate.format(date));
```

The reason your code is failing because after converting the date, it will converted to for example in the below format:

> Jan 25 2019 08:11:21

And you are trying to append this with the screenshot path.

> String finalImage = (screenShotLocation+
>   dateFormat.format(localDate)+"_" +imgName +".png");

The above 'finalmage' value is looks like this:

> .\src\main\java\com\phpTravels\screenshots\Jan 25 2019 08:11:21\someName.png

As per the windows file naming rules, the colon(':') operator is not allowed in the file names. So the reason your code is failing.

For more info, refer this

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file)